# Fi-ware hadoop ,not running hadoop "hello world" -> word count

Tags: hadoop, fiware-cygnus

I'm trying get working a hadoop hello world code that is 100% based on wordcount, but the fiware platform returns a error while I'm trying to run this code as a job with his rest api.

The following code just runs fine in my private hadoop cluster that I use for testing proposes, but no inside the fi-ware platform and I don't know why.

The code is just this:

```
  package smartive;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.*;   
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

  public class Hello {
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper < LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable > {
      private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();

          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector < Text, IntWritable > output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
              String line = value.toString();
              StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
              while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                  word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                  output.collect(word, one);
              }
          }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer < Text,
      IntWritable,
      Text,
      IntWritable > {
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator < IntWritable > values, OutputCollector < Text, IntWritable > output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
              int sum = 0;
                  while (values.hasNext()) {
                      sum += values.next().get();
                  }
              output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
          }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Hello.class);

        conf.setJobName("Hello");
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
  }
```

I compile the previously code with javac the I make a jar package with the entry point set as smartive.Hello.

The, I run the following rest call to cosmos.lab.fiware:

```
curl -X POST "http://computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org:12000/tidoop/v1/user/myuser/jobs" -d '{"jar":"Hello.jar","class_name":"Hello","lib_jars":"","input":"data/in","output":"data/out"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: myOauth2token"
```

But I got as a result

```
{"success":"false","error":1}
```

The expected response must be like this:

```
{"success":"true","job_id": "job_1460639183882_0001"}
```

But I don't know how I can debug on the new cosmos since there is no ssh interface and no error msg on the response.

The files are ok inside data/in folder (test.txt file) and the folder data and data/in has 777 permissions.

Anyone has some hint / idea where/what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114945/discussion-on-question-by-alex-b-fi-ware-hadoop-not-running-hadoop-hello-worl).